# Cannot spoof MacOS version disabling SIP

Tags: macos, terminal, mojave, plist, sip

I've been trying to spoof my Mac version because I need to install an app for school that doesn't support Mac OS Mojave. The application does not have a burned in Info.plist file so I cannot modify that either. I can't update the OS because I need 32 bit application support. Anyways, I decided to follow the common steps of spoofing the version and disabled SIP by running `csrutil disable` from Recovery Mode. I disabled it and moved on to the next steps.

1. `/sbin/mount -wu`
2. `cd /System/Library/CoreServices`
3. `nano SystemVersion.plist`

I replaced the necessary spaces from 10.14.6 to 10.15. I got the error `Error writing SystemVersion.plist:Read-only file system`

I'm confused because I disabled SIP and followed all of the steps. Does MacOS Mojave end support for editing SystemVersion.plist? What have I done wrong and what can I do?

Comment: If the application requires Catalina, why do you expect it to run on Mojave?

Comment: I was going to spoof the Mac version and trick the installer. I don't want to upgrade to Catalina since it doesn't have 32 bit application support.

Comment: What does "tricking the installer" have to do with whether the application runs on Catalina?  If the application specifies Catalina for compatability, then it will be using API's particular to Catalina.

Comment: if you really want to do this do sudo : sudo nano SystemVersion.plist  BTW, you may go into compatibility problem and the application may not run.